# 502 Bad Gateway downtime while deploying in AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway, http-status-code-502

i have a problem with AKS and the implementation of AGIC, whenever i make an actualization to my deployment i experience 5 to 10 minutes of downtime with the error 502 bad gateway. this only happens after i update an already existing deployment.

After searching a bit on the internet i stumbled with a post from microsoft talking on how to "Minimizing Downtime During Deployments" with AGIC but this does not seem to solve the issue, any idea or guidance on how to mitigate this?

Answer (score 0):

***Need to check below:***

1. Deploy your application into multiple AKS clusters across different regions. Choose regions where AKS is available when deploying multiple AKS clusters.
2. Deploy your application across many AKS clusters in different regions to protect your system against region failure. Consider AKS region availability when deciding where to put your AKS cluster, choose regions close to your users, and couple two regions together.
3. Direct all application traffic through Traffic Manager before it reaches your AKS cluster for maximum performance and redundancy. Azure Traffic Manager is a DNS-based traffic load balancer that allows network traffic to be distributed across regions.
4. Keep your container images in Azure Container Registry and replicate the registry to each AKS region.

Refer [MSDoc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/aks/operator-best-practices-multi-region.md) for more relevant information regarding the issue.